# Can't run Visual Studio 2022 profiler after wiping %TEMP% folder

Tags: windows, visual-studio, ide, profiling, visual-studio-2022

After I had had issues with my PC's storage excessive usage, I figured out that I have %TEMP% folder which consumes 40GB of memory. I completely wiped it out, but now my Visual Studio 2022's profiler doesn't work. I have error in `Output` window: `Exception of type 'Microsoft.DiagnosticsHub.Diagnostics.CollectionStartFailedHubException' was thrown`. Also I have this error in `Output`: `Could not found specified file (HRESULT: 0xe1110002)`. I can't assert that those errors are related to %TEMP% folder, but still. In addition, I'm trying to run "CPU Usage" profiler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you did something bad to VisualStudioTemp folder. You can see the path in Visual Studio Installer.

[image]

If you did deleted this folder unfortunately, the simplest solution is to delete the whole Visual Studio and to reinstall it.

If not, [the following steps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/592556/diagnostics-session-failed-to-start) may be helpful to you:

- Press ⊞ + R
- Type services.msc
- Click OK
- Enable the Visual Studio Standard Collector Service 150
- Find the Visual Studio Standard Collector Service 150 in the service list
- Right-click on its name
- Click Start

Good luck.